# redirect in Grails controller

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I'm new to Grails , i'm using Grails version 2.3.4 , in my application i have 2 controllers

> AppUser

and

> ManageLicences

, in the AppUsers there is a method named auth and below its code :

```
def auth()
{
    if (!params.username.empty)
    {
  redirect  (controller: "manageLicences" , action:"checkLicense")
     }
}
```

In the checkLicense in the ManageLicense controller i'm doing some redirects depending on some conditions

```
def checkLicense {
if (someCondition) {
    redirect (controller:'manageLicences' , action:'list')
        }
    else {
        redirect  (controller:'appUsers' , action:'login' )

        }
}
```

, the problem is that when my application reaches

```
 redirect  (controller: "manageLicences" , action:"checkLicense")
```

in the AppUsers controller , rather going to the redirect that  in checkLicense , the URL in the browser will be

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/manageLicences/checkLicense
```

and blank page , any advice ?

Comment: any advice or recommendations ?

Comment: Make sure you have a `return` statement after each `redirect` call.

Comment: Add some logging in,before, and after the 'if' to see what's happening.

Comment: i added     'return' but nothing  happened

Comment: any other recommendations ?

Comment: do you know if you are making it to 'checkLicense' before the condition statement?  Did you add return statements after all redirects?  Looks like in the end either 'list' in ManageLicencesController or 'login' in AppUsersController will be called.  Do you have actions and views defined for both?

Answer (score 4):

Check that you're not doing redirect from a namespaced controller to a controller that is not in a namespace.

According to [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Controllers/redirect.html):

> Redirects the current action to another action, optionally passing parameters and/or errors. When issuing a redirect from a namespaced controller, the namespace for the target controller is implied to be that of the controller initiating the redirect. To issue a redirect from a namespaced controller to a controller that is not in a namespace, the namespace must be explicitly specified with a value of null as shown below.

```groovy
class SomeController {
    static namespace = 'someNamespace'
    def index() {
        // issue a redirect to PersonController which does not define a namespace
        redirect action: 'list', controller: 'person', namespace: null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkLicense {
    if (someCondition) {
        redirect (controller:'manageLicences' , action:'list')
        return
    } else {
        redirect  (controller:'appUsers' , action:'login' )
        return
    }
}
```